# android: how start apk from another apk?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, apk

I have two different apk. In the first I saved one activity that creates a layout. In the second apk I have a view and other classes that the activity on the other apk uses. How I can connect them together?

Comment: Use package name in the intent to call one app from another.

Comment: @Sanket990: your link installs a new apk, rather than opening another app.

Answer (score 1):

You should find the package name of the new apk:

```
     Intent newApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     newApp.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.newApp.package","com.newApp.package.Activity"));
     startActivity(newApp);
```

If you only have the target package name, that's fine too. You can find its launch `Intent` using PackageManager:

```
Intent i;
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("target app package name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.newapp.packagename", "com.newapp.packagename.Activity"));
        intent.putExtra("KEY", value);
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Install New App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: @DownVoter:- can you please tell me what is wrong in this code? So that I can improve my knowledge